# bash: to remove lines with the same beginning

Tags: bash, sed

There is a file with contents like

```
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO aa
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO bb
2016-03-24 22:10:06,903 INFO cc
2016-03-24 22:10:07,804 INFO dd
2016-03-24 22:10:07,904 INFO ee
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO ff
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO gg
```

I want to remove the lines that have the same beginning (the part before `INFO blab-bla-bla...`).
I can perform it with full-featured programming languages like Ruby but because of the file size and some other reasons I'd like to use `sed`.

The expected result:

```
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO aa
2016-03-24 22:10:06,903 INFO cc
2016-03-24 22:10:07,804 INFO dd
2016-03-24 22:10:07,904 INFO ee
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO ff
```

In the past in order to remove the same lines I've used the command

> sed '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1$/!P; D'

which, if I understand correctly, reads input line, then appends the next line with \n (if it's not the last line) to the pattern space and then, if there is a sequence like "any line from beginning till \n plus the same line till the line end", prints the second line and deletes it.

I tried to create a bit more complicated sed command using the above-mentioned one but not succeeded, there is at least one logical block left:

```
cat temp.log | sed '$!N; s/ INFO.*//; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

What I wanted to do was to remove everything starting with `INFO` from the current line, then append the next line,

```
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO bb
```

remove everything starting with `INFO` there,

```
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399
```

and then to remove the second line if they are identical. How to perform replacing for the next line? I tried several things with `\1` and `&` but without effect.

Comment: your `ff` and `gg` lines has identical datetime with `aa` and `bb`

Comment: `ff`, `gg` lines shouldn't be present

Comment: Why `..,399` appears twice in the expected result?

Comment: @hek2mgl because for this case it is enough to check only the next line, not all of them.

Comment: @nonrandom_passer, in one of your comments you state that input is sorted by timestamp but the OP still shows otherwise (first and last 2 lines are all the same timestamp - aa, bb, ff and gg). Which is it?

Comment: @svante, real input is sorted by timestamp, what I've posted here was just an example to show removing the next line (only) if its beginning it the same as in the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you are using sed commands other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool as all the other sed constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

```
$ awk '{c=$1$2} p!=c; {p=c}' file
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO aa
2016-03-24 22:10:06,903 INFO cc
2016-03-24 22:10:07,804 INFO dd
2016-03-24 22:10:07,904 INFO ee
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO ff
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood from your question, here is another possible `awk` script:

```
awk -F"[, ]" 'prev!=$3; {prev=$3}' file
```

It will strip out all lines based the 3rd element having the same value as the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

command:

```
awk -F" INFO " 'seen[$1]==0{print; seen[$1]++;next}  seen[$1]==1{seen[$1]=0}' sample.csv
```

use " INFO " as field delimiter and store first field into an array `seen`, 1st field is the datetime before INFO. If the datetime is not in array, seen[$1] returns false and `!` will make it true. `++` is increment operator it increases the occurrence time

`seen[$1]==1{seen[$1]=0}` reset value to 0 if see a consecutive duplicate datetime

Comment: missing last output line.

Comment: seems that this variant removes all other duplicates in a file, not only in the next line, right? I also noticed that while testing I got an empty line in the end of the edited file, but it's completely ok.

Comment: @nonrandom_passer this doesn't match the expected output.  If you changed your mind please edit your original post and set the record straight.

Comment: edited to meet the expected result. Please see my comment on the original question. My first answer was based on the description.Thanks you all :)

Comment: @EdMorton actually, this answer was kinda overkill. in this particular case I don't need to find duplicates in other lines because they are sorted by timestamp, but it is nice anyway. Besides, it uses INFO as a delimiter which is handy.

Comment: @EdMorton Your variant seems both brief and logical, so it becomes accepted. Although all of the answers are cool, thanks.

Comment: @nonrandom_passer but your posted sample input is not sorted by timestamp. It's important when posting sample input/output that it closely reflects your real data otherwise you'll get answers to some problem you don't have.

Comment: @EdMorton, you are right. I've just posted an example to show removing the next line (only) if its beginning is the same as in the previous line

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `uniq`. The following simple line will do exactly what you want by comparing only the first 23 characters (the date and time):

```
$ uniq -w 23 temp.log
```

Comment: thanks, nice for a case when there is always fixed amount of characters.

Comment: Actually, this works with any amount of characters as long as the  timestamp format stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

here is an unorthodox solution...

```
$ rev file | uniq -f2 | rev

2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO aa
2016-03-24 22:10:06,903 INFO cc
2016-03-24 22:10:07,804 INFO dd
2016-03-24 22:10:07,904 INFO ee
2016-03-24 22:10:05,399 INFO ff
```

Comment: thanks, good one. the delimiter can be only a space? have not found in its man an option to change delimiter.

Comment: Yes, uniq only recognizes white space as a delimiter

Comment: another question here is how this variant would work with big files compared to sed/awk, for example.

Comment: size doesn't matter.

Comment: This works as long as there are always exactly two fields (INFO and xx) after the date/time information.  If there can be a variable number of (space separated) fields after the date/time, then it doesn't work correctly.  This means it is a solution for the current data set, but not necessarily for a more general data set.

Comment: Cool but works only if last two columns have no whitespace (similar to what @JonathanLeffler also noted).

Comment: Yes, this is not a general solution, depends that that are exactly one field after INFO.